# A two-column layout with different order of elements when transformed into one-column layout

Tags: html, css

I'm trying two create a two-column layout that looks like this:

[image: two column]

which on smaller screens would become a one-column layout looking like this:

[image]

**What is tricky about it, is the order of elements - I want A and B to be first in respectively left and right column, while being the first and second elements in the single column layout.**

I've managed to get a result like this with flex layout using the following code:

```
<html>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .break {
            flex-basis: 100%;
            order: 0;
            height: 0;
            width: 0;
        }
        #wrapper {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .block-wrapper {
            width: 50%;
        }
        .block-wrapper h1, .block-wrapper p {
            padding: 10px;
        }
        #a {
            order: -1;
            background-color: magenta;
        }
        #b {
            order: 1;
            background-color: red;
        }
        #c {
            order: -1;
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        #d {
            order: 1;
            background-color: orange;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .block-wrapper {
                width: 100%;
            }
            #a, #b, #c, #d {
                order: 0;
            }
            .break {
                display: none;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="a" class="block-wrapper">
                <h1>A</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="b" class="block-wrapper">
                <h1>B</h1>
                <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                <p>amet</p>
            </div>
            <div class="break"></div>
            <div id="c" class="block-wrapper">
                <h1>C</h1>
                <p>lorem </p>
                <p>ipsum</p>
                <p>dolor</p>
            </div>
            <div id="d" class="block-wrapper">
                <h1>D</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

(for some reason it does not work when I put it as a code snippet, but it works just like on the screenshots when saved as HTML file and opened)

The problem with this approach is that it requires `#wrapper` to have set height and breaks when an element cannot fit in the height (the element lands off-screen). Which does not work for my case, because the content of the items is going to be dynamic and can become quite long (the whole page containing this layout is supposed to have a vertical scrollbar).

Would it be possible to get such a result with CSS only? What are your ideas?

Comment: If you don't want to use flexbox my only other experience solving this issue with CSS is with CSS Grid. You could do that with just `grid-template-columns` like this: https://codepen.io/Bertw/pen/BapYWdZ or get it looking a little more like your example with `grid-template-areas`: https://codepen.io/Bertw/pen/gOgvmgw (I re-worked your code to be mobile-first too, was easier for me to work on solution that way)

Comment: If you have a lot more content `grid-template-areas` might become cumbersome to deal with

Comment: SO adds a !doctype html to the snippet and this is what breaks your layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: My original answer claimed that this could not be done with CSS alone. While this is true of the general 'masonry' case, in the case of a maximum of just two columns as in the question it can be done with use of floats.

Here's a snippet using the HTML from the question unaltered. You will need a clear:both after it (if clearing both columns before the next content is required).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  /* set for this test - obviously set to what is required */
}

.wrapper:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(n) {
  width: 50%;
}

.wrapper:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(odd) {
  float: left;
}

.wrapper:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(even) {
  float: right;
}

.a {
  background-color: magenta;
}

.b {
  background-color: red;
}

.c {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.d {
  background-color: orange;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .wrapper:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(n) {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .wrapper:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(odd) {
    float: left;
  }
  .wrapper:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(even) {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a">
    <h1>A</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <h1>B</h1>
    <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
    <p>amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    <h1>C</h1>
    <p>lorem </p>
    <p>ipsum</p>
    <p>dolor</p>
  </div>
  <div class="d">
    <h1>D</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is an proposed extension to CSS grid, masonry, which will cope with more than 2 columns. Firefox has this built-in but you need to set `layout.css.grid-template-masonry-value.enabled` in the advanced preferences in about:config. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Masonry_Layout) and the link from there to a useful description of this feature in [Smashing Magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/native-css-masonry-layout-css-grid/)

Comment: Thanks! It's much simpler than I expected and works great :D I have only one question:  The ":nth-child(1)" after ".wrapper" in the CSS seems redundant or is there some sense to it?

Comment: Apologies - yes I think it is redundant. It stems from my initial attempt which had two .wrappers. I too was thinking more complex than was necessary!

Comment: @AHaworth Am I right that this unfortunately won't work, when box A is higher than B?
.a {height: 150px} .b {height: 149px}

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is solved.

```css
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
}
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color: magenta;">
    <h2>A</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color: red;">
    <h2>B</h2>
    <p>lorem ipsum dolor amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color: yellow;">
    <h2>C</h2>
    <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color: orange;">
    <h2>D</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work so well as the divs do not grow with the content. And if you remove the height parameter to let them, they always align in a simple grid - so if B is big and A small, there is a lot of free space between A and C. But @A Haworth's solution works perfectly. :)